# FireDac problem with Postgres and libpq.dll x64

Tags: postgresql, delphi, firedac, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am using Delphi ent 10.4 with FireDac connection to Postgresql.
The app is a 64bit FireMonkey interface to a Postgresql database.

I have a FDConnection set to PG and a FDPGPhysDriverLink with the path set to an x64 Libpq.dll for version 12. When I test the connection, I get an error about the driver and
a complaint about needing x86 bitness.

Can someone please help me with this. I am writing a 64 bit app and the docs for this state that FireDac works with x86 or x64.

Also up to what version of pg does Delphi/FireMonkey/FireDac support? The documentation isn't very clear on this.

Exact error:

> Error: [FireDAC][Phys][PG]-314. Cannot load vendor library [C:\Roots\Bin\Postgres\x64 12\libpq.dll]. Library has unsupported architecture [x64]. Required [x86].
> %1 is not a valid Win32 application
> Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has x86 bitness.

In the Object Inspector, I clicked the Connected option for the FDConnection.

This is from the Embarcadero wiki "Windows Client Software
FireDAC requires the LIBPQ.DLL x86 or **x64 client** library for connecting to the PostgreSQL server."

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "_I test the connection_" - how exactly? "_I get an error about_" - which software says so? Cite the exact error message.

Comment: I added the exact error msg.

Comment: The IDE is 32-bit, so it's going to need to have the 32-bit DLL available, which is why you're getting the error that it can't load the 64-bit version. Either install the 32-bit version so that the IDE can use it, or don't test your connection in the IDE, and just try to run your app to see if it works.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I didn't consider the ide limitation. So I might need to reconsider using FireDac as the last pg that supported 32bit was 10.

Comment: @Dennis445 They added 32bit client libraries back after a while once they realized they are still needed for a lot of users/applications.

Comment: The last win 32 libs I can find are for postgresql-10.23. everything else newer is x64.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting LIBPQ.DLL in the same folder as your EXE? Keep in mind that when you are running it from the IDE that you will need to copy LIBPQ.DLL into the Win32\Debug and/or Win64\Debug folders under the source folder.

I don't know if that helps but good luck.

Comment: I only have a win 64 build option I removed all of the other build configurations. I did try the x86 dll for a win 32 build and it work properly. The x64 does not work with or without the dll's in the build directory. I did order the FireDac book but it's a couple of weeks away from being delivered. I am hoping I can get this resolved before then. I am really curious if FireDac wants both 32 and 64bit installed or if it really only works with 32bit. I tried searching for an answer but this topic seems absent at least to me.

Comment: The Postgres ODBC 64 bit driver will have the version of the DLLs that you need. Just install and grab the DLLs and place them in the folder of the application as per my original reply.  You can get it here.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.PostgreSQLODBCDriver3264bit

Comment: Thanks for the info, The information above explains the the ide is limited to 32bit at design time. So I will setup a simple connection and try out the x64 dll's and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need the current 32 bit version of *libpq.dll* in your path. You can download the latest version of 32 bit postgres from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/dll/).

If you want to run a 64 bit app, you must then change the path to point to the 64 bit *libpq.dll* and connect the `TFDConnection` (and activate the tables) in run time. However, you need the 32bit to set up your tables in design time.
Also see [my question on the subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77399866/how-to-connect-to-delphi-11-3-ce-32-bit-with-postgres-16-64-bit/77584465?noredirect=1#comment136898732_77584465)
I hope this helps and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is explained by Anderson Games on his YouTube channel "Conectando PostgreSQL 64 bits com um projeto no RAD Studio". Everything started up for me. All the best!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).