# How to Connect To Delphi 11.3 CE 32 bit With Postgres 16 64 bit?

Tags: postgresql, delphi, postgresql-13

I am trying to connect to a DB made with Postgres 13. The problem is, Delphi is a 32 bit program and Postgres is 64 bit. Delphi says it needs 32 bit, but there are no 32 bit files for version 16.

I tried the files from version 13, 32 bit but I get the message

> "[FireDAC][Phys][PG]-314. Cannot load vendor library [C:\Melvin's
> Programs\Win32\Debug\New door program\libpq.dll]. Library has
> unsupported architecture [x64]. Required [x86]. %1 is not a valid
> Win32 application Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE
> directories, and has x86 bitness.."

### Edit

I was incorrect. The DB was made in Postgres 13. I previously stated that it was v16. Both are 64 bit.

Comment: You need to compile a 64bit app and then do the DB connections in run time.

Comment: How do you connect to the tables? Is there no way you can do that in design time with 32 bit binaries?

Comment: You can try to download the latest older version (Version 10.23) of  32 bit binaries from here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries and copy all the dll's somewhere you can use in your client app.  Never tried it, but it might work (I mean the version is still supported, so it can be somewhat compatible with the newer version).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Leonard Version 10.x isn't supported anymore. The latest supported version is now 11.x which doesn't have 32-bit anymore. So you really shouldn't be using v10.x or any of those older versions. You can see which ones are supported and which ones aren't here: https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ (Support for Version 10.x ended last year already and support for Version 11.x is ending next week)

Comment: @ErrorInCode Currently as it stands, you can't use Postgres during design-time in Delphi due to the Delphi IDE not having a 64bit version. So you'll sadly need to do everything in run-time via code.

Comment: I have Delphi Sydney, PostgreSQL 16 64bit. I just used the 32bit odbc DLLs to connect up at design time. https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

Comment: @FLDelphi So on the site it looks like you can get 32 bit files for v16? What files are included?

Comment: libpq.dll (and supporting files) + psqlodbc30a.dll and psqlodbc35w.dll.

Comment: Thank you much. I will test it and respond when I get time. Thank you.

Comment: So now I get the error -

"[FireDAC][Phys][PG]-314. Cannot load vendor library [libpq.dll]. The specified module could not be found
Hint: check it is in the PATH or application EXE directories, and has x86 bitness.."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a 64 bits *Postgresql* running and my aplication is a 32 bits.

You have to use the 32bit version of *libpq.dll*

Comment: I downloaded the 32 bit libpq.dll and put it in the folder with all the forms and files, and I also tried in the 32 bit or 64 bit specific folder. This error is with these files in the folder.

Comment: Is it the same error as before?

In addition to the LibPq.dll file, others are needed to work, for example: LIBEAY32.dll, LIBICONV-2.dll, LIBINTL-8.dll, PGENLIST.dll, PGENLIST.dll, SSLEAY32.dll

You can get them all by installing the postgres 32bit ODBC driver

Comment: I installed the driver in the program files and copied them into the dev folder, however, not all the files you mentioned seem to be in there?

Comment: Hello, I have an older version of the LibPq.dll, but you can download the latest version in: [link](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/dll/) 'https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/dll/' . Just don't copy the files named "psqlodbc*.dll"

Answer (score 0):

The path was incorrect. It seems it defaulted to a previous path. A `TFDPhysDriverLink` with the *venderlib* property set to the correct path with the correct files solved the problem. Thanks everyone for all your time!